# "Native" Geolocation versus "PhoneGap-based" Geolocation Features

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Technically speaking, are there important differences if comparing (what, informally, here I'm calling) "native" [1] **Geolocation** *versus* a "**PhoneGap**-based" **Geolocation** features?

Are there some "limitations" when using **PhoneGap** to develop (a complete) location-based app?

Cheers,

-- Paulo Zanetti.

[1] for "native", I mean iOS and Android **native** Geolocation capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

"PhoneGap-based" Geolocation is "Native" Geolocation. PhoneGap utilizes JavaScript to access native features, like Geolocation. You are able to get the devices position and track movement just as you would natively.

Every Geolocation query with PhoneGap returns, if successful, eight things:

- Latitude
- Longitude
- Altitude
- Accuracy
- Altitude Accuracy
- Heading
- Speed
- Timestamp

You can set different options too, for example `enableHighAccuracy` which enables higher accuracy, but can take a little longer, though often not noticeable.

You can read more about it on the [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation).